# Find surface ode or pde

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to find differential equation of the two surfaces connecting/spanning semi-circles with their  diameters on x-axis:

$ x^2 + y^2 = 1 ,  x^2 + z^2 = 1 $

with Gauss curvature $K = -1$,

and, Mean curvature $H = 0 $ ?